# Call instance method in class method in Python

Tags: python, instance, self, class-method

I'm designing one class for common library.

This class method called sequencially like below.

call order is 'class method' -> 'instance method' -> 'instance method'

I don't know why last instance method need self parameter..

Ordinally instance method does not need self method as we know.

What am I missing?

```py
class A:
    @classmethod
    def first(cls):
        print('cls method')
        cls.second(cls)

    def second(self):
        print('inst method 1')
        self.third(self)  # Question! Why this method need [self] parameter?

    def third(self):
        print('inst method 2')

A.first()
```

Comment: You're calling `second` as a class method.  If you want to call it with a class rather than a class instance, then make it a `@classmethod`.  For `third`, if it doesn't need a class or a class instance, then make it a `@staticmethod`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of how you're calling `second`.

Say you have such a class:

```
class A:

    def do_thing(self):
        pass
```

The following are equivalent:

```
a = A()
a.do_thing()

A.do_thing(a)
```

In other words, when we call a method of an instance, it is the same as looking up a function attribute of the class object and calling it *with that instance as the first argument*.

Now, note that when you call `second`, you pass `cls` to it. That is the *class object* and not an instance, which means that you're doing something like `A.do_thing`. Therefore, for it to know which instance you want to call `third` on, you need to pass in `self`.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you're missing out is that you're not creating an instance for your class.

Try this-

```
class A:
    @classmethod
    def first(cls):
        print('cls method')
        cls.second(cls)

    def second(self):
        print('inst method 1')
        self.third(self)

    def third(self):
        print('inst method 2')

instance = A()
instance.first()
```

This should give you your desired output. As for why the last method needs self as a parameter, self refers to the instance that you're applying the method on, and thus you can change it's properties with it. Let me give you an example-

```
class Kid():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def change_age(self, age):
        self.age = age

tom = Kid('Tom', 13)
print(tom.age) #prints 13
tom.change_age(14)
print(tom.age) #prints 14
```

Here, with the `self` argument in the method, Python would know which instances' property `age` does it have to change.
In your use case, it might seem not to make much sense though. I hope this helps. :)